# MS Word addin formatiing table and text alongisde each other

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am writing a Word addin in C# that will add a set of text and a table at the current selection point in the document and what is happening at present is when the button is clicked the table and text will be inserted but the text will be inside the table.

Mainly, I need to get the text out of the table but ideally what I would like is for the text to be separate but alongside the table, so text aligned to the left and table aligned to the right.

What I have presently:
[image]

What I would like:
[image]

Code I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;

using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordAddIn1
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range textFromDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
            textFromDoc.Font.Size = 10;
            textFromDoc.Font.Name = "Verdana";
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;

            if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.Overtype)
            {
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.Overtype = false;
            }

            object missing = System.Type.Missing;
            Word.Range currentRange = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
            Word.Table newTable = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(
            currentRange, 1, 2, ref missing, ref missing);

            // Get all of the borders except for the diagonal borders.
            Word.Border[] borders = new Word.Border[6];
            borders[0] = newTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft];
            borders[1] = newTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderRight];
            borders[2] = newTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderTop];
            borders[3] = newTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom];
            borders[4] = newTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderHorizontal];
            borders[5] = newTable.Borders[Word.WdBorderType.wdBorderVertical];

            // Format each of the borders.
            foreach (Word.Border border in borders)
            {
                border.LineStyle = Word.WdLineStyle.wdLineStyleSingle;
                border.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlack;
            }

            Word.Cell cell = newTable.Cell(1, 1);
            cell.Range.Text = "Name";
            Word.Cell cell1 = newTable.Cell(1, 2);
            cell1.Range.Text = "Eman";

            if (currentSelection.Type == Word.WdSelectionType.wdSelectionIP)
            {               
                //currentSelection.
                currentSelection.Font.Size = 15;
                currentSelection.Font.Name = "Arial Black";
                currentSelection.Font.Bold = 1;
                currentSelection.Font.Color = (Word.WdColor)(0 + 0x100 * 84 + 0x10000 * 164);
                currentSelection.TypeText("Test\nTest\nTest\nTest\nTest");
                currentSelection.TypeParagraph();
            }
            else
                if (currentSelection.Type == Word.WdSelectionType.wdSelectionNormal)
            {
                // Move to start of selection.
                if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.ReplaceSelection)
                {
                    object direction = Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart;
                    currentSelection.Collapse(ref direction);
                }
                currentSelection.TypeText("Inserting before a text block. ");
                currentSelection.TypeParagraph();
            }
            else
            {
                // Do nothing.
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a table with 2 columns and no borders. Inside the first column put the text. Inside the 2nd column, put your current table.

Comment: I don't have time right now to verify this and enter it as an answer, but inserting a table typically moves the selection to the table's first cell. Make the table text-wrapped, get its anchor (it's of type `Range`), and insert the text there.